# Poor SpriteKit performance on iPhone 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, swift, sprite-kit

I'm attempting to write a SpriteKit game but am quickly running into issues. As you can see below I'm drawing ~350 simple nodes on the screen. This produces ~25fps on my iPhone 6+.

Basically I'm just creating `Section` objects (which is a SKNode), inside each of those I am looping 20 times and adding the individual blocks. The blocks are slowly moved up the screen. I'm not exactly sure where to start debugging this or which part of the code to show so here's an excerpt from the Section class that append the blocks:

```
for i in 1...20 {
            let left = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: n, height: n))
            left.fillColor = randomColor()
            left.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: n - 1, height: n - 1))
            left.physicsBody?.dynamic = false


            left.position.x = (CGFloat(i) * n) - (size.width/2 + n/2)
            row.addChild(left)
            cubes.append(left)
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Every box has a physics body (so you could try and use less bodies). Bit masks to reduce the number of intersection checks done by the physics engine

Answer (score 8):

Your nodes are all skshapenodes. Each shape node generates a new draw call, that's why you have 368 draws in that scene - which is a lot even on the latest phone.

It is my opinion that SkShapeNode was never intended as a game-building node but rather one you can visualize debugging info with. One should not build a game largely based or dependent on shape nodes simply because it is highly inefficient.

Instead, use sprites with actual textures, you'll see much better performance. If the screenshot is representative of the game's graphics you only need a white, square image as texture, then change individual sprite's color properties to tint them.

Comment: How about creating SKTextures from nodes and then simply using the textures ? Wouldn't it reduce the draw calls to... 5 in the case of the OP?

Comment: You could do that as well but honestly, I think it'll be easier and faster to just create a square, white image and use that as texture.

Answer (score 0):

LearnCocos2D is correct, Your problem isn't the number of nodes it's the number of draw calls.

In your case you don't even need textures, you can create SKSpriteNodes from just a colour and a size. Only thing is you'll lose the white stroke.

You might be able to drop this right in:

```
for i in 1...20 {
    let left = SKSpriteNode(color: randdomColor(), size: CGSize(width: n, height: n))
    left.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: n - 1, height: n - 1))
    left.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    left.position.x = (CGFloat(i) * n) - (size.width/2 + n/2)
    row.addChild(left)
    cubes.append(left)
}
```